# Python connect to FTP Error:NotImplementedError

Tags: python, ftp, openshift, pyftpsync

I want to use the Python module pyftpsync module (on rhc openshift server).But when I connect to the ftp server, it causes an error. but i could  connect to the ftp server with FileZilla software from my pc.

The code is here:

```
cd /tmp

cat << 'EOF' > ftp_sync2.py
from ftpsync.synchronizers import DownloadSynchronizer, UploadSynchronizer,BiDirSynchronizer

from ftpsync.targets import FsTarget #, UploadSynchronizer, DownloadSynchronizer
from ftpsync.ftp_target import FtpTarget
import os

env_var = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR']
#local = FsTarget(env_var+"/app-root/runtime/repo/php/")
local = FsTarget('/tmp/')

passwd = "ss123456"

ip='f12-preview.atspace.me';user='XXXXXXXX';#  XXXXXXXXX@yahoo.om

#ip='XXXXXXX';user='XXXXXXX';# X@yahoo.om
ip='ftp.ucq.me';user='XXXXXX';#  wXr@yahoo.om
ip='X';user='ssasa';#  X@yahoo.om
ip='f13-preview.awardspace.net';user='X';passwd='X'#
```

X@yahoo.om

```
remote = FtpTarget("/home/www/", ip,21, user, passwd)
#remote = FtpTarget("/work/communiuty", ip,21, user, passwd)
remote = FtpTarget("/", ip,21, user, passwd)

opts = {"force": False, "delete_unmatched": False, "verbose": 3, "execute": True, "dry_run" : False}

s = UploadSynchronizer(local, remote, opts)

s.run()
stats = s.get_stats()
print(stats)
EOF

nohup sh -c " ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/python/bin/python ftp_sync2.py"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync2.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync2.log
```

And the error is here:

```
Upload /tmp
                  to ftp:f13-preview.awardspace.net/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp_sync2.py", line 29, in <module>
    s.run()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/565e0df60c1e661889000146/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/synchronizers.py", line 128, in run
    res = self._sync_dir()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/565e0df60c1e661889000146/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/synchronizers.py", line 375, in _sync_dir
    remote_entries = self.remote.get_dir()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/565e0df60c1e661889000146/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 270, in get_dir
    self.ftp.retrlines("MLSD", _addline)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/565e0df60c1e661889000146/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 443, in retrlines
    callback(line)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/565e0df60c1e661889000146/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 263, in _addline
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I suspect that one of the ftp commands that you are loading is not implemented on the server. Try issuing the commands manually until you find the one that is causing the issue.

Comment: when i run the ** s.run()  ** code it cause this error.

Comment: This is a ftpsync issue not an openshift issue. You should look at the source for 

  File "/var/lib/openshift/565e0df60c1e661889000146/app-root/runtime/srv/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyftpsync-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/ftpsync/ftp_target.py", line 263, in _addline

for what is not implemented.

Comment: @SoheilPaper `s.run()` is a composite of the values in local, remote and opts, so you need to test which of the values, probably in opts, is causing your problem.